# Recreatable HTML Form

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML Form with some fields. I want to add two buttons to it. First two recreate a new set of all the fields in this form on the next line. Second to delete any of the newly recreated set of fields.

```
<form action="">
  <label for="college">College</label>
  <input name="college" type="text" />

  <label for="degree">Degree</label>
  <input name="degree" type="text" />

  <label for="discipline">Discipline</label>
  <input name="discipline" type="text" />

  <label for="passout-year">Passout Year</label>
  <input name="passout-year" type="number" min="2000" max="2021" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript. You cannot modify the DOM with just HTML in such a way

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var cln=form.cloneNode(true);` to clone a particular element or a whole form and then just append it to the body of the document using `document.body.appendChild(cln);`

run the code snippet to see how it works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function copyForm(){
            var form=document.getElementById("form1");
            var cln = form.cloneNode(true);
            document.body.appendChild(cln);
        }
    
    function deleteForm(event){
        event.parentElement.remove();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" name="copy" value="add new form" onclick="copyForm();">
    <form id="form1" action="">
  <label for="college">College</label>
  <input name="college" type="text" />

  <label for="degree">Degree</label>
  <input name="degree" type="text" />

  <label for="discipline">Discipline</label>
  <input name="discipline" type="text" />

  <label for="passout-year">Passout Year</label>
  <input name="passout-year" type="number" min="2000" max="2021" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="button" value="delete form" onclick="deleteForm(this);" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You Pravin. This is what I exactly needed. What if I also want to a button to delete the added field ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use only html, or you can use JS or if you want you can use HTML and JS to make it more dynamic,:-

[You can refer this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-with-the-javascript/)

Comment: Okay. Thank You. I didn't found solution with only HTML